# Center ul in container while keeping li inside left aligned

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there is a way to center an ul inside its container, while the li inside are left aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/82dzt0te/1/

```
#container ul {
    text-align: left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#container ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you resize the screen in a way that the li wrap to the next line a white space appears on the right as a column. The idea is not to have the right white border. (The li would be all of the same size)

How could this be achieved (if possible)?

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve. http://oi58.tinypic.com/2j674ex.jpg

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/82dzt0te/2/

Comment: or like this? http://jsfiddle.net/82dzt0te/4/

Comment: please provide feedback so that we may help you, or clarify your question as it's confusing

Comment: Hi! In the first case you would only have one element per line and in the second case you centered all elements. I'm trying to have the elements (or images) aligned to the left while the whole ul structure is centered in its  container. Maybe this isn't even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS you're looking for:

```
#container ul {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82dzt0te/6/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case you would have the li elements centered and I'm trying to have the li aligned to the left and center the whole ul inside its the container.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex layouts:

http://jsfiddle.net/x579701e/

```
#container ul 
{
    text-align: left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container ul li 
{
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

#container img {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: i don't think this is what he's asking for

Comment: he can achieve what he needs with a flex layout

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is [in this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/82dzt0te/8/)

you need to give the `ul` a `width` property. If you'd like it to resize, it should be a % not px. Then give it a margin of `0 auto` which you already did.

keep in mind, `margin:0 auto` doesn't work if you don't provide a width.

***UPDATE***

[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/82dzt0te/11/)

Comment: Yes I think that's the exact issue. I want to do it without assigning a width. So I believe what I want to do is not possible without a width.

Comment: hmm... it might be, I'll need to investigate further

Comment: I understand what you did. But it only solves the issue for one line of items. As soon as an element wraps down you get the space on the right.

Comment: can you post an image of what you want it to look like? or an example on a website somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with "display: table;" on ul. This way you don't have to depend on the ul width to make the content centered and the li elements will have the text aligned to the left. Like this:

```
#nav {

}

#container ul {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#container ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

You can check the demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kswxs6v1/